# Heroku buildpack git push failure

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to install FFMPEG on my nodejs server.

What i did:

`heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi`
or
`heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi`
or
`heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi`

I have created a `.buildpacks` (without extesion) file at my github repository. This is what it includes:

`https://github.com/jayzes/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg`
`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodej`

Each time i am trying to push my changes to heroku, this is what i get:

```
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... failed
 !     Push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack
```

Currently, i am trying to return to the default buildpack (i have removed the .buildpacks file from my git repository) using:
`heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL`
and i am still getting an error while pushing my git repository to the heroku. Any suggestions?

Comment: The solution was: `heroku buildpack:set https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git -a lecturus`, `git push heroku master`